# Image gallery that is opened via a preview with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox, image-gallery

I wanted to create an image gallery that opens via a preview and links to another page where the images are located.

like this one https://fancyapps.com/playground/XU. but the link must call up and open the image gallery located on another page.

I tried using ajax but I can't. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear:

"links to another page where the images are located"
"open the image gallery located on another page".

If you're thinking that Fancybox will load the content of another page to find the gallery links and then use those to display the image gallery, sorry, but that's not supported.

But you can always create your own click handler that determined the content source and then use the `Fancybox.show()` method to programmatically start Fancybox.